# Hardened PHP deployment on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, php

I've been asked to create a PHP environment on a web-server I administer that is currently only running Python applications. The authors of these applications don't necessarily have a programming background, so I'd like to limit what they can possibly do wrong.

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04, and know that I should have `register_globals` disabled, but what else can/should I restrict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.starhost.ro/Linux-Tutorials/php-hardening.html) is a list of things that I was about to type up. There are other things you can do, like [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/), but the first link is a good start to this.

Comment: In Ubuntu, apt-get install php-suhosin will get you that.

Comment: It is still working for me..

Answer (score 4):

As you can't really trust your app developers to write secure code, you'll have to limit the attack vectors non-secure php code could provide. Using user input without proper sanitizing as SQL or as an argument to open() are classic examples of things that go wrong.

My brief list:

- put the php environment inside a chroot jail, to limit the risks to the host.
- make sure the php apps don't access the same databases which are used otherwise.
- rate-limit (and monitor) outgoing mail. If there's a way to send email with user-specified content and address, some spammer will sooner or later find and exploit it.

I'm sure there are plenty of other things I either don't know about or I can't remember any more.

There are also plenty of stuff you as an administrator can't prepare for. For example, it's very hard to control cross-site scripting risks and to make sure mechanics inside the apps don't encourage any malicious use cases, such as using the app as a drop box for bad stuff like rootkits.